# Dynatree jquery plugin add custom properties to node

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I would like to add new properties to [DynatreeNode class](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#h8.3). For example in methods OnSelect I want to use node.myproperty. node.myproperty value is calculated from some DOM element. Is there a way to do this? I tried using jQuery extend, but it does'nt seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

this is JavaScript, so you can create a new attribute virtually everywhere, simply by assigning it ;-)

For Dynatree, the recommended place would be the `node.data` object, e.g.

```
node.data.foo = "bar";
```

then access it:

```
onSelect(node){
    if(node.data.foo !== undefined){
        alert(node.data.foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if "foo" property should be accessible OnSelect, getNodeByKey, getActiveNode etc? How to make all node instances have property foo?

Comment: if you assigned it, it's there. Otherwise it is `undefined`. I Edit the sample

Comment: mar10, let "foo" be a function for example node.data.foo = function() { return $("#someTextBox").val() }. I would like use property "foo" in multiple contexts for example in onSelect, onActivate etc. The node should have property "foo" which is is always accessible not 'undefined'.

Comment: You could add functions to the DynatreeNode prototype. This is rather a JavaScript question than a Dynatree question.

Comment: actually, i was thinking about using DynaTreeNode.prototype, to implement a function like marcinn wrote, but the property I define this way is not being added. I try to do that in jquery ready() and in dynatree onrender(), but i get nothing. Perhaps you know what I might be doing wrong